# Multiplying tensors of size [batch] and size [batch, features] in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Basically I have two tensors that I am trying to multiply two tensors (one is simply size [batch] (ie a tensor with a single value for each batch), and a tensor of size [batch, x, y, z]) such that each 3D tensor in the batch gets scaled by its corresponding value

currently, I have attempting the following but I've yet to find a way that works!:

```
enc_out1 = tf.math.multiply(enc_out1, w_int, name=None)
#enc_out1 has shape [batch, x, y, z], w_int has shape [batch]
```

any and all help is much appreciated

Comment: `w_int[:, None, None, None] * enc_out1`

Answer (score 0):

You could just reshape it.
Here is an example

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.ones(shape=(4,3,3,3), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([[1],[2],[3],[4]], dtype=tf.float32)

c = tf.math.multiply(tf.reshape(a,shape=(4,27)),b)
c = tf.reshape(c, shape=(4,3,3,3))

tf.print(c)
```